# Global vs Static variables in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I understand that the keyword `static` can be used to limit scope. However, say I have two versions of the same class:

```
// MyClass.m
// Version 1 
static NSString *const MyVar = @"Some Value";

@implementation MyClass
...
```

And the second version:

```
// MyClass.m
// Version 2
NSString *const MyVar = @"Some Value";

@implementation MyClass
...
```

Since `MyVar` is never exposed and is only available within this file (`MyClass.m`) then what are the implications / differences (if any) of how `MyVar` are defined since the scope is always global to this file?

**NOTE**: Neither version exposes `MyVar` in the Header file.

Comment: Can you explain how you have two `MyClass.m` files with the same class? Are they both members of the same target? They can't both be or you will have lots of issues. Or are you saying you have only one such file but you want to know the difference between `MyVar` being static or not?

Comment: The later. I'm simply illustrating two separate versions of the file. Meaning, each is a candidate for the final implementation. Not two classes a part of the same target/project.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks for referring me to that SO question. For some reason I couldn't find someone else asking the same Question.

Comment: I used [this search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bobjective-c%5D+static+global) and found a good one matching your question.